# Indicator above bar in graph

Tags: highcharts

We have a highcharts chart displaying bars for Pass, Honor, Fail in a course. The chart shows the percentage of students for each as a vertical bar. 
I would like to have an indicator above the bar that the particular student being viewed fit. So for example if the student received a Pass for the course there would be some indicator/graphic above the Pass bar. See image as an example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`

---

1.Custom path using `renderer.path()` method (eg. arrow):

```
arrow = chart.renderer.path([
  'M', x, y,
  'L', x - size, y - size,
  'L', x - size / 3, y - size,
  'L', x - size / 3, y - 3 * size,
  'L', x + size / 3, y - 3 * size,
  'L', x + size / 3, y - size,
  'L', x + size, y - size,
  'z'
]).attr({
  fill: 'orange',
  stroke: '#000',
  'stroke-width': 1
}).add().toFront();
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aor76xtn/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

---

2.Image using `renderer.image()` method:

```
arrow = chart.renderer.image(
  'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',
  x - size / 2,
  y - size,
  size,
  size
).add().toFront();
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/upyx3z0m/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image